# How to use a dataframe attributes inside of a for in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to python so I'll try detailed as possible.

I'm trying to implement the bagging algorithm on it (i need to implement for my final paper, so basically i can't use one that is already implemented).

I have a CSV file with X classes. What i want to do is read the csv with pandas, and after i have read i want to create one dataframe for each class read of the csv file and at the end create a new CSV file with all these new DataFrames. I already did this for a specific CSV file, but I need to make it generic.

This is the code that i made. It works for one specific CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

#Function of percentage
def percentage(number1, number2):
    percent = (number1 * number2) / 100
    return percent

#read the csv file
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('Monk.csv', sep=',')

#select all the values of the dataframe with the column class = 1, do the same for class = 2
class1 = dataFrame[dataFrame['Class'] == 1]
class2 = dataFrame[dataFrame['Class'] == 2]

#reset the index of the new dataframes
class1 = class1.reset_index(drop=True)
class2 = class2.reset_index(drop=True)

#return the quantity of rows
lenClass1 = class1.__len__()
lenClass2 = class2.__len__()

#randomly select n rows of eache class dataframe
randClass1 = class1.sample(n=int(percentage(lenClass1, 33)))
randClass2 = class2.sample(n=int(percentage(lenClass2, 33)))

subSet= randClass1.append(randClass2)
subSet = subSet.sample(frac=1)
subSet = subSet.reset_index(drop=True)
subSet.to_csv('MonkSub1.csv', sep=',')
```

With this code i get this:

dataframe

```
     A1    A2    Class
01   a     b      1
02   x     a      2
03   f     a      2
04   r     b      1
05   l     a      2
06   s     b      1
```

after the that i separate the dataframe in new dataframes

Class1

```
     A1    A2    Class
01   a     b      1
04   r     b      1
06   s     b      1
```

Class 2

```
     A1    A2    Class    
02   x     a      2
03   f     a      2
05   l     a      2
```

then i reset the index

Class1

```
     A1    A2    Class
01   a     b      1
02   r     b      1
03   s     b      1
```

Class 2

```
     A1    A2    Class    
01   x     a      2
02   f     a      2
03   l     a      2
```

So i select a number of rows randomly of each new DataFrame based on a percentage of rows in each DataFrame, and create a new CSV with this rows that were selected. For example, with 33% i will have 1 row of Class1 and 1 row of Class2 selected ramdonly.

NewCSV

```
     A1    A2    Class    
02   r     b      1
01   x     a      2
```

And finally i reset the index of this new DataFrame.

After this i tried to do the same for generic files. My idea was to read a CSV file with pandas, after that group in separates DataFrames by 'Class'(like the example above) with similar values. And in this parte is the problem. I tried that usign the `groupby()` function, but using the `type()` function of the new DataFrame i get `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`. With a DataFrameGroupBy i couldn't use all the attributes of a DataFrame, then i use this:

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('Monk.csv', sep=',')    
grouped = dataFrame.groupby(["Class"])
test= grouped.apply(lambda x:x)
```

When i use the `type()` function to print `test` it returns: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. Basically i did all i wanted, but after that my problems begin. I need to save all the new DataFrames on a list or array, to iterate over them and reset the index (`reset_index()`), take a sample with a percentage value based on the total of rows(`sample()`) and others functions that i could use in a DataFrame, but i can't because inside of a for i can't use all this DataFrames attributes.

```
for df in test.iterrows():
    FrameList = [df]
    FrameList.reset_index(drop= True)
```

But i got the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`.
I don't know what to do, i already tried a lot of things, but none of them works.

ps: Sorry for bad english!!

Comment: Can you add some [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) data with expected output?

Comment: you can try groupby().groups and proceed. I'm still not sure what you want to do.

Comment: I tried to put a example on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to create a subset of a larger file where the classes in the subset are proportional to those in the larger file. You need a stratified sample.

If you have a dataframe like so with the following class summary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': list('aabbb')*4,
                   'val': np.arange(20)}); df

Out[106]: 
   class  val
0      a    0
1      a    1
2      b    2
3      b    3
4      b    4
5      a    5
6      a    6
7      b    7
8      b    8
9      b    9
10     a   10
11     a   11
12     b   12
13     b   13
14     b   14
15     a   15
16     a   16
17     b   17
18     b   18
19     b   19

df.groupby('class').count()
Out[107]: 
       val
class     
a        8
b       12
```

If you want to create a 25% (to keep the math simple) stratified sample by 'class', then your final dataframe will have 5 obs with 2 from 'a' and 3 from 'b' to maintain proportionality. That can easily be done like so.

```
dfsub = df.groupby('class', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=.25)).reset_index(drop=True); dfsub
Out[109]: 
  class  val
0     a    0
1     a    6
2     b   18
3     b   17
4     b    7
```

From here you can write it out to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
for df in test.iterrows():
    FrameList = [df]
    FrameList.reset_index(drop= True)
```

> But i got the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute
>   'reset_index'. I don't know what to do, i already tried a lot of
>   things, but none of them works

`FrameList = [df]` creates a new list that contains a dataframe...

`reset_index()` is a method of the dataframe object, but you are calling it on the list, not the dataframe itself.

Comment: I tried doing it:

`for df in test.iterrows():
       df.reste_index(drop = True)`

and i doesn't works. I still got an error message.



`df.reset_index(drop=True)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`